# Kinect ambient light information

Tags: ros, kinect, driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

when I play with the Xbox I get warnings in case of a probably disturbance of the Kinect by ambient light. Is such an information available in one of the ROS-Kinect drivers?

Thanks for your help

Poseidonius

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38619/kinect-ambient-light-information/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2012-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Never heard about such packages, but seems one is easy to write: it just has to warn you whenever you have to many NaN values in your depth.

---

Originally posted by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) with karma: 386 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1